# How not to start Windows(Electron.js) app when installation is finished?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, windows, electron

When my app finishes installing the app is automatically started, before this installer is closed with the "Finish" button. Is there a way to not start it, or to start it when this "Finish" button is clicked?
I am using Silent Install Builder, https://www.silentinstall.org/
and electron-rebuild https://github.com/electron/rebuild

I am attaching a screenshot so you can see what is happening.

[image]

Comment: Hm that "Silent Install Builder" doesn't seem to be very well documented. Basically what you need is to execute something "post install". Some other solutions like electron-builder allow you to add a postInstall hook. You can check it out here: https://www.electron.build/index.html Also, keep in mind that Electron team maintain their own packager solution: https://github.com/electron/electron-packager